# Switch ignores predefined case and jumps to default case

Tags: c, switch-statement, mingw

First, I want to explain briefly what I am doing. I am making a disassembler, but the problem is in the prefix recognizer routine. The following function receives a byte and compare it with the prefix table. It must display a string according to the prefix. For example CS override byte display 'CS '.

But there's a problem. It works fine with almost every prefix, except LOCK, REP, and REPNE. When you enter their values to the function, it displays "UNDEF" (default case if the value has no entry in the switch statement)

But the compiler is wrong: I have a case for the three prefixes (LOCK, REP, and REPNE). I can't understand why it takes the default case ignoring the predefined cases. I have looked in the internet, but I can't find an answer to my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

///Prefixes lock and repeat (group one)

#define prefix_lock  0xF0
#define prefix_repne 0xF2
#define prefix_rep 0xF3

///Prefixes segmet override (group two)
#define prefix_cs_override      0x2E
#define prefix_ss_override      0x36
#define prefix_ds_override      0x3E
#define prefix_es_override      0x26
#define prefix_fs_override      0x64
#define prefix_gs_override      0x65

///Branch hints goes here.

///Operand-size override (group three)
#define prefix_operand_size_override    0x66

///Address-size override (group four)
#define prefix_address_size_override    0x67



int show_prefixe(FILE *my_output, char prefix){
    switch(prefix){
        case prefix_lock:
            fprintf(my_output, "LOCK ");
            break;
        case prefix_repne:
            fprintf(my_output, "REPNE ");
            break;
        case prefix_rep:
            fprintf(my_output, "REP ");
            break;
        case prefix_ss_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "SS ");
            break;
        case prefix_cs_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "CS ");
            break;
        case prefix_ds_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "DS ");
            break;
        case prefix_es_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "ES ");
            break;
        case prefix_fs_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "FS ");
            break;
        case prefix_gs_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "GS ");
            break;
        case prefix_operand_size_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "OP ");
            break;
        case prefix_address_size_override:
            fprintf(my_output, "ADDR ");
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(my_output, "UNDEF ");
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *output;
    output = fopen("C:\\prefix.asm", "wb");
    show_prefixe(output, prefix_rep);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Is the compiler wrong? Can it has a bug? I am using MinGW in Codeblocks.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please construct a minimal test-case.

Comment: What Oliver said. The purpose is to figure out where you're wrong, it's almost unthinkable that you found such a basic bug in gcc.

Comment: Also, compile at the maximum warning level.

Comment: I think the problem is between signed and unsigned char. If you put unsigned char for prefix, it should work.

Comment: "test.c:29:9: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type [enabled by default]" (Using gcc 4.8.2)

Comment: I think that my code is a minimal test-case. It is just a small code. If I change it, it could don't reflect the original problem. I will try to simplify it.

Comment: Thanks you. @Arrigo You are right. I have change char to unsigned char and it works!! Thanks.

Comment: @Martin: It's not.  For a start, it involves reading a file.  A minimal test-case is entirely self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing unsigned char to your function. The problem should be that 0xF3 for example is 243 and you are using a (signed) char which can not support such a value.

```
int show_prefixe(FILE *my_output, unsigned char prefix) { ...
```

Further, your function is supposed to return something, so say you return 0 in the end of the switch statement.

Comment: If I use a signed integer with a value outside of its maximum range, Could happen the same problem?? It is just a curiosity